# Create a program to inject XML code into a file

Tags: xml, windows

I am looking to create a program that essentially creates an XML file and injects specific code based on check boxes.

Example: User clicks box for "Action A" and it writes to a file the specific line of code needed for that action.

My goal is to make it easy for end users to generate XML files for an application without understanding XML in general.

What coding language should I use?
What language would allow for a graphical interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe go with Java. You can use Netbeans IDE for that. You can use Swing in java to create the UI and Java I/O to output the XML to be generated by user responses.